# Mock a scheduleWithFixedDelay method using EasyMock

Tags: unit-testing, testing, easymock

How can I mock the start() function in the following code using easyMock?

```
class A {

    public runOnce(Integer a) {
       // do something
    }

    public void start() {
        executor.scheduleWithFixedDelay(() -> runOnce(12), 0, 1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }
}
```

I tried in the following way which is not working:

```
ScheduledExecutorService executorService = createMock(ScheduledExecutorService.class);
executorService.scheduleWithFixedDelay(anyObject(), eq(0), eq(1000), eq(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));
expectLastCall().andReturn(null);

A a = createMockBuilder(A.class).addMockedMethod(A.class.getDeclaredMethod("runOnce", Integer.class)).createMock();

a.runOnce(12);
expectLastCall();

replay(executorService);
a.start();
verify(executorService);
```

Can someone suggest how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems here. First, you are not injecting the mocked `executorService` into your `A` instance. I will assume you can use a constructor to do that.

```
A a = createMockBuilder(A.class)
        .addMockedMethod(A.class.getDeclaredMethod("runOnce", Integer.class))
        .withConstructor(executorService)
        .createMock();
```

Then, matchers need to take the correct types in parameter. So here `scheduleWithFixedDelay` expects `long`. So the expect should be

```
expect(executorService.scheduleWithFixedDelay(anyObject(), eq(0L), eq(1000L), eq(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)))
    .andReturn(null);
```

Doing this makes everything run smoothly.